# .exe works in cmdline, not in matlab unix()

Tags: bash, matlab, unix

I am attempting to use MatLab to run myexecutable.exe in Ubuntu 14.04.3.

The executable runs in the command line just fine, in other words:
`./myexecutable.exe < inputfile` in the cmdline runs and gives the desired output

However, if I attempt to use MatLab to run this command:

`[status,cmdout] = unix('./myexecutable.exe < inputfile')`, I get the following error:

> /bin/bash: ./myexecutable.exe: No such file or directory

I have tried:

-Doing this command by specifying the entire file path of the executable as well as the input file

-adding a `unix('cd /home/my/executable/file/path')` to the Matlab file before the command to run the .exe

-setting all permissions to the executable and input file to 777

-checking that MatLab recognizes both the .exe and the input file exist using: `unix('file myexecutable.exe'), unix('file inputfile')`, which returns the output indicating that MatLab knows the files are there (such as the output 'ELF 32-bit LSB  executable') for the .exe

-checking ldd on the .exe to make sure all libraries are properly linked, which they are

I still get the 'No such file or directory' error. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Please post the _exact and full_ error message.

Comment: The full and exact error message is:

status =

   127


cmdout =

/bin/bash: ./anopp-L31v1-linux.exe: No such file or directory

Comment: `unix('cd /home/my/executable/file/path')` won't do anything. You need to specify your full path in your command. Or navigate to the location in question by using `cd` (not `unix('cd')`) within Matlab.

Comment: I have also tried within the MatLab .m file (which is in the same directory as the .exe file): cd /home/my/executable/file/path then [status,cmdout] = unix('/home/my/executable/file/path/myexecutable.exe < inputfile'), as well as [status,cmdout] = unix('/home/my/executable/file/path/myexecutable.exe < home/my/executable/file/path/inputfile'). I am still getting the same error of: /bin/bash: my executable.exe: No such file or directory

Comment: Does your actual path have spaces or any strange characters in it? Can your successfully execute `[status,cmdout] = unix('ls /home/my/executable/file/path/')`? And shouldn't you put a `.` in front of your full path to the executable, i.e., `[status,cmdout] = unix('./home/my/executable/file/path/myexecutable.exe < home/my/executable/file/path/inputfile')`?

Comment: Leaving the Matlab error aside, are you sure that a .exe (Windows executable) will run in Ubuntu?

Comment: The actual path is has no special characters. I am also able to obtain an output (all the file names in the directory) when running [status,cmdout] = unix('ls /home/my/executable/file/path/') in MatLab

Comment: I am able to run the .exe through the linux command line just fine. It does run on Ubuntu (through the command line). It is configured for linux systems (I've used another version of this .exe on a Mac as well with no problems). It is just running it through MatLab that is creating the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried it without the `./`?

It seems as though Matlab is looking for the file `./myexecutable.exe` and not understanding what `./` means. Or, Matlab may have another way of denoting the current working directory.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with and without the ./ for both the .exe and the input file, as well as writing out the full directory path to both the .exe and input file. This includes the path obtained from commanding 'pwd' in MatLab for the folder the .exe and input file are in. Is there another possible notation I am missing?